# Send bytes to SPI controller using Assembly

Tags: assembly, spi, uefi

I am studying UEFI Firmware development. For debuging purpose, I need to send some read / write commands to SPI controller.

Is there any way to communicate with SPI controller using assembly language?

I am using `Dediprog EM100Pro` as emulator and `GigaDevice GD25LQ64` as SPI Flash chip.

Comment: Yes, of course. However, it's hard to answer this question without more information. It depends on how you connect the device to the motherboard, I'm not aware of any commercial motherboard that provides an external SPI interface. Intel PCHs have a generic SPI controller and GIOs which are pretty intuitive. You can use them the usual way: configure them through PCIe, you access them through  MMIO.